# TFS Query for Individual Daily Completed Work

Tags: tfs, tfs-web-access

My company uses TFS to manage our Agile workflow.  I would like to build a TFS query that will show which individual team members reduced the Remaining Work field on Tasks assigned to them.  Alternatively (or in addition) I'd like to build a query to show which individual team members increased the Completed Work field on Tasks assigned to them.  Is this possible in TFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that because you cannot have time based statements in your query (what was the Remaining Work yesterday, for example) you are not going to be able to compare a field from today with a field from yesterday.  TFS simply does not have this capability (at least in the web access view).

Comment: Sadly, TFS is lacking in the ability to compare state from date to date, as you have said.  I feel sorry for anyone who has to use it.  Jira is an infinitely better choice.